# Unable to format a drive (Unknown Error)

Tags: c#, format, wmi

I'm using the WMI Volume ManagementObject to format a drive ([Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432(v=vs.85).aspx)). If I try to do this from a non-elevated application, I get a result code of `3` (Access denied) which makes sense. Running the application as an administrator means I get a return code of `18` (Unknown Error).

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    String.Format("select * from Win32_Volume WHERE DriveLetter = \"{0}\"", Drive));

foreach (ManagementObject vi in searcher.Get()) {
    FormatResult result = (FormatResult)(int)(uint)vi.InvokeMethod("Format", new object[] { FileSystem, QuickFormat, ClusterSize, Label, EnableCompression });
    if (result != FormatResult.Success) {
        throw new FormatFailedException(String.Format("{0} (Error code {1})", result.ToString(), (int)result));
    }
}
```

Parameters:

```
FileSystem: "NTFS"
Quick: false
ClusterSize: 4096
Label: "Test"
EnableCompression: false
```

I can format the drive with the above parameters through Explorer without any problems. How can I diagnose the issue and find out what's going on?

Since there seems to be some confusion, `FormatResult` is just an enum to simplify handling return codes...

```
enum FormatResult {
    Success = 0,
    UnsupportedFileSystem = 1,
    IncompatibleMediaInDrive = 2,
    AccessDenied = 3,
    CallCanceled = 4,
    ...
    UnknownError = 18
}
```

To give an idea of what I'm doing:

[image: Screenshot]

Since the docs mention that this method is usually called asynchronously, I've tried switching to an Async call with the same result (code available upon request). I've also tried various combinations of FileSystem (NTFS/FAT32), ClusterSize (including `0` to let the system pick a default), and Quick/Full formats. All give the same result of `18`.

What am I missing?

Comment: [Formatting a Drive WMI CodeProject working example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115598/Formatting-a-Drive-using-C-and-WMI)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yep, that's where I lifted the code from originally

Comment: have you read this MSDN article as well ..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826699(v=vs.85).aspx instead of throwing your own error could you not wrap the code in a try{}catch{} and capture the exception message there..? which may give you more meaningful explanation

Comment: I hadn't read that article. The WMI call doesn't throw an exception, it gives a return code. (0 on success, non-0 on failure as per the linked docs). I can't see any info in that article re: throwing exceptions and as mentioned in the question, I'm running the binary elevated so UAC shouldn't be an issue. Unless there's something I'm missing?

Comment: I understand that you are running as Elevated.. perhaps there are some other issues when trying to do this remotely.. which if you think about it.. could lead to Malicious behavior what if you wanted to reformat a co-workers machine via WMI or a Server for example.. why not just run a typical / normal batchfile that can handle that.. lol

Comment: I'm not doing this remotely. I need to put the same set of files on ~400 USB drives. The app detects when a new removable drive is plugged in, formats it and copies the files... This plus a couple of USB hubs should save me a lot of time. As far as I can tell, this is the only way to format a drive from C# (without 400+ cmd prompts which is nasty and hacky)

Comment: so how do you insure that the USB drive(s) can read the C# .net executable  code wouldn't you need some sort of partition on that USB that can read as well as execute .NET.. I am curious I've never done this using USB

Comment: @DJKRAZE Other way 'round... The app running from a local drive takes a Source folder then sits and waits for a removable drive to be plugged in. Drive is wiped, source folder is copied, drive is "Ejected". New drive is plugged in. Wash, rinse and repeat. Screenshot added